# pig@hadoop: processing local files without hdfs with multiple cores

Tags: hadoop, multiprocessing, apache-pig

If I run pig@hadoop in the local mode (because I do not want to use hdfs) then it process my scripts in single-thread/single process mode. If I setup the hadoop in pseudo mode (hdfs with replication=1) then pig@hadoop does not like my `file:///...`:

```
traj = LOAD 'file:///root/traj'
   USING org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.CSVExcelStorage(
        ';', 'NO_MULTILINE', 'UNIX', 'SKIP_INPUT_HEADER'
   ) AS
   (
     a1:chararray,
     a2:long,
     a3:long,
     a4:float,
     a5:float,
     a6:float,
     a7:chararray,
     a8:float,
     a9:chararray
   );

c = FOREACH (GROUP traj ALL) GENERATE COUNT(traj);
dump c;
```

is there any way to tell pig@hadoop to process the files in multi-core mode without putting the files into hdfs?

Answer (score 1):

**Local Mode** - To run Pig in local mode, you need access to a single machine; all files are installed and run using your local host and file system. Specify local mode using the -x flag (pig -x local).

**Mapreduce Mode** - To run Pig in mapreduce mode, you need access to a Hadoop cluster and HDFS installation. Mapreduce mode is the default mode; you can, but don't need to, specify it using the -x flag (pig OR pig -x mapreduce).

Source : http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.9.1/start.html#execution-modes

If you want to run it in local mode, you should switch pig into local mode using command `$ pig -x local`. By default pig run on MapReduce mode and reads data from HDFS.

To run Pig in local mode, you only need access to a single machine. To make things simple, copy your files to your current working directory (you may want to create a temp directory and move to it) provide that location in  your pig script.

Comment: I am able to run pig both locally and with external mapreduce mode (which runs in pseudo mode), pretty much the way you described it. If i run pig in mapreduce mode, pig complains about `file:///root/traj` (cannot access, although the files are there locally). How can I process files in hadoop or local mode without hdfs?

Comment: If you have switched pig in local mode then it will pic file from your local directory and will run on local mode. Again if you want to run in MapReduce mode then you need to switch it on MapReduce mode using command `$ pig -x mapreduce` and file should be available in HDFS location.

Comment: in the local mode (`pig -x local`) I can access all the local files but the processing is limited to one core. In mapreduce mode (`pig -x maprecude`) I have 32 Cores available, but have problems accessing local files.. How can  I get both?

Comment: You can't get both at a time. You can choose only one at a time. Parallel processing is a advantage of Hadoop therefor you should use HDFS instead of local mode for fast processing of the job.